# How to attach an event listener to a JavaScript generated html tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-events

I would like to attach an event listener (e.g. 'click') to a programatically added JavaScript generated code (every line of a table). Usually, I would normally do that with jQuery dirty `on` method, but it doesn't work (seems that my selector is too much specific. I don't know any way to do this in another way...

```
var STD.prototype.addTableWithEvent(id, eventName, eventFunction)
{
    var ident = "webapp_table_"+ id;
    var table = angular.element("<table id=\"#"+ ident +"\"></table>");
    var line = angular.element("<tr></tr>");

    // this is the line not working
    jQuery("body").on(eventName, '#'+ ident +' tr', { std: this }, eventFunction);

    line.appendTo(table);
    this.$compile(table)(this.$scope);
    table.appendTo('body');
};
```

This function is then called this way:

```
 var std = new STD();
 std.addTable("example", "click", function() { console.log("working"); });
```

The table is well added to the page, but the event function is not called when I click. If I change for this :

```
jQuery("body").on(eventName, 'tr', { std: this }, eventFunction);
```

Then it's working but for every table, which is not what I want.
Is there a way to do this with Angular.js or jQuery?

Comment: `$.on`is not _dirty_ at all.

Comment: @moonwave99 Dirty as I feel dirty using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try attaching the event to the table instead of the body, and set the selector to delegate it to the `<tr>` elements, like so:

```
 table.on(eventName, 'tr', { std: this }, eventFunction);
```

Comment: Yeah it works, thought it wouldn't as the table is also javascript generated ! :)

Comment: in fact, I had to use directly : `table.on(eventName, 'tr', { std: this }, eventFunction);`

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
jQuery("body").on(eventName, 'tr', { std: this }, eventFunction);
```

will attach an event handler to every `<tr>` element on your page -- all tables. To narrow it down and be more specific, just use standard css selectors to narrow your selection.

Like this:

```
jQuery("body").on(eventName, '#desiredTableID tr', { std: this }, eventFunction);
```

or

```
jQuery(document).on(eventName, '#desiredTableID tr', { std: this }, eventFunction);
```

Comment: Look at my code, it is exactly what I am doing, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. Honestly, I think you could also have solved it by binding to the `document` via `.on()` and specifying the precise table's `tr` that you wanted to target. However, very happy it is resolved. Generally, when you modify a DOM element (body, in your case, via the `append` method) you must then use `.on()` [against a DOM object or element higher in the hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation). Also, if all `tr` elements on entire page are triggering, then be more specific, as above. Hope you experiment with this a bit.

Comment: Yes, may be I should have been adding it to the DOM before binding the events and it would have work.